# upload screenshot to itunes connect

Tags: ios, image, app-store, screenshot

I have created an app that I want to deploy to the app store. It asks me for screenshots (at least 10) of them in a size of `1242 x 2208` if I'm correct. My mobile (iPhone SE) only makes `640x1096` screenshots, how can I make a bigger screenshot?

Comment: Simply run on iPhone 8 Plus simulator, take screenshot and upload it.

Comment: you can use simulators

Comment: But screenshot size of simulators is only `994x2152`.. that's why I thought there has to be another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use simulator and be sure to uncheck the "Optimize Rendering for Window Size" option in order to take screenshot in real screen size.

To deactivate the option go to **Debug** and unchek the **Optimize Rendering for Window Size** option.